# Can I nest functions in Hibernate custom dialect?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a hibernate model that needs to support multiple databases (MySQL, Oracle, Sybase etc) and has some date logic in it. Going over various forums / posts I came across the idea of creating custom dialects for Hibernate and registering a function, with database-specific logic for each dialect. These worked beautifully (showing just the relevant bits - apologies in advance, I had to obfuscate some of the values and field names for the post):

```
public MyOracle10gDialect() {
    super();
    SQLFunctionTemplate sqlFunctionTemplate = 
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.DATE, "SYSDATE - ?1");

    registerFunction("date_sub_days", sqlFunctionTemplate);
}

public MyMySQLDialect() {
    super();
    SQLFunctionTemplate sqlFunctionTemplate = 
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.DATE, "DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL ?1 DAY)");
    registerFunction("date_sub_days", sqlFunctionTemplate);
}
```

Now however I need to use a function to resolve the parameter to pass into this function. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code that uses this model otherwise I would just move the logic into code, but is there any way to do nested functions? I want to use 'GREATEST(x, y ,z)' as the parameter to my 'date_sub_days' function. I basically want this to work and am failing:

```
WHERE date_sub_days(GREATEST(:TRADE_HISTORY_MAX_DAYS,:ORDER_HISTORY_MAX_DAYS,:NEG_HISTORY_MAX_DAYS)) &lt; value1
```

because it doesn't resolve the 'greatest' function into a single parameter.

In MySQL I get the following printed to console:

```
Hibernate: 
select blah from blah where
    DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL GREATEST(? DAY) < value1 
ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

And in Oracle I get the following printed to console:

```
Hibernate: 
select blah from blah where 
SYSDATE - GREATEST(?<value1
ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Invalid column index
```

Would love to hear suggestions on how to implement this in either the dialect or a change in the HQL.

Comment: Any thoughts at all on this? If I can't get this to work it may invalidate my entire design of using Custom Dialects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to get the nested functions to work, but I did come up with a surprisingly simple workaround. It lacks the code re-use that I was aiming for (so any changes will have to be made to all functions) but at least it allows me to carry on with using the Custom Dialects.

Instead of trying to nest the functions:

```
WHERE date_sub_days(GREATEST(:TRADE_HISTORY_MAX_DAYS,:ORDER_HISTORY_MAX_DAYS,:NEG_HISTORY_MAX_DAYS))
```

I created a separate function taking in more parameters:

```
WHERE date_sub_days_greatest(:TRADE_HISTORY_MAX_DAYS,:ORDER_HISTORY_MAX_DAYS,:NEG_HISTORY_MAX_DAYS)
```

and nested the logic at the Dialect level:

```
SQLFunctionTemplate dateSubDaysFunction = new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.DATE, "SYSDATE - ?1");
registerFunction("date_sub_days", dateSubDaysFunction);

SQLFunctionTemplate dateSubDaysGreatestFunction = new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.DATE, "SYSDATE - GREATEST(?1,?2,?3)");
registerFunction("date_sub_days_greatest", dateSubDaysGreatestFunction);
```

Hope that helps someone else out there!